# Prove or disprove the following inequality

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, inequality, expectation, integral-inequality

If $X$ is a non-constant random variable with $X \geq 0$ then
$$[E(X^{\alpha+1})]^{\alpha}-[E(X^{\alpha})]^{\alpha+1} > 0$$ 
for 
$\alpha=1,2,3,4,...$

It is easy for $\alpha=1$, because this is same as variance. But for other values of $\alpha$, I am confused. Also I could not find any counter example for $\alpha=2,3$ etc. But how to prove then if this is correct.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: use Holder inequality

Comment: Related post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289607/the-map-gt-ext-frac-1t-is-monotonic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [another similar answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1193208/290189).

Let $L^p=(\Omega, {\cal A}, \mu)$ and $p<q$.
$$\int_\Omega X^p d\mu = \int_\Omega (X^q)^{p/q} d\mu \le \int_\Omega X^q d\mu$$
by Jensen's inequality and the concavity of the function $y\mapsto y^\alpha$ for $\alpha=p/q<1$.  Raise both sides to the power $1/p$ and you get
$$\left(\int_\Omega {X^p dx}\right)^{1/p} < \left(\int_\Omega{X^q dx}\right)^{1/q}.$$
Note that equality holds if and only if $X$ is a constant or the concave function in the equality is linear.  Since both are false, it's a strict inequality.

In particular, when $p=\alpha$ and $q=\alpha+1$, we have $[E(X^{\alpha+1})]^{\alpha}-[E(X^{\alpha})]^{\alpha+1} > 0$.

Comment: Is this the Lyapunov's  inequality? By the way thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: [Yes, it is.](http://www.opentradingsystem.com/quantNotes/Lyapunov_inequality_.html)